# IntWritable.set(IntWritable) is throwing error

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, reduce

While writing sample code to test customdata in **hadoop**. I am getting the following error:

> The method set(int) in the type IntWritable is not applicable for the
>   arguments (IntWritable)

I have checked the `set` method for `IntWritable.set(int value)`. 
How can I convert a hadoop `IntWritable` in to `Int` and then back to `IntWritable#set` method will convert back to `IntWritable`.

```
public class customText implements Writable{

private Text depName;

//default constr
private IntWritable depId;
customText(){
    this.depName = new Text();
    this.depId = new IntWritable();

}

customText(Text depName , IntWritable depId ){

    this.depName.set(depName);
    this.depId.set(depId);
```

I have also tried `this.depid=depId` but it did not worked.

Thanks

Comment: [`IntWritable.get()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html#get())? Really, you should always consult the documentation before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
customText(Text depName , IntWritable depId ){
    this.depName.set(depName);
    this.depId.set(depId.get());
}
```

The method signature for set is `set(int value)`, so you have to `get()` the int from the `IntWritable`.

Comment: Thanks again @Binary Nerd for the help